# The role is not issued when clicking on the reaction

Tags: c#, discord.net

My exception says that user = null but I don't understand why? UserId is passed in the debugger

```
 private async Task ReactionAdd(Cacheable<IUserMessage, ulong> cache, ISocketMessageChannel socketMessageChannel, SocketReaction reaction)
            {
                if (reaction.MessageId == 771361839917170748)
                {
                    var emote = Emote.Parse("<:NepSmug:740928682310500412>").ToString();
    
                    if (reaction.Emote.ToString() == emote)
                    {
                        var sockettextChannel = socketMessageChannel as SocketTextChannel; 
                        
                            ulong roleid = 741342300499738715;
    
                            var role = sockettextChannel.Guild.GetRole(roleid);
                            var user = sockettextChannel.Guild.GetUser(reaction.UserId);
    
                            await user.AddRoleAsync(role);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

The user is null might caused by recent change on the Discrod API refer to [this](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1656#issuecomment-719755306). The changes caused the `Guild.User` info is not downloaded properly.

1. First thing to check is if the User is assigned on `Context.Guild` or not (You can also verify if the user in your Discord server is equal on the `Context.Guild.Users`).
2. Second you need to enable this feature on your Discord Bot
   [image]