# Discord.Net GetUser By Id Returns null

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I was coding a bot for Discord using Discord.net. I have an `IGuild` where I need to get a User by id, so I'm using:

```
var user = await guild.GetUserAsync(id, CacheMode.AllowDownload);
```

This should get the user if cached, and if not, download it. But the user is null every time.

I know the id is correct.
Is there a proper way to do this?

The Server has > 1k members so downloading them through `DownloadUsersAsync` takes way too long.

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604209/the-role-is-not-issued-when-clicking-on-the-reaction mainly it's because `intent setting`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arriving late to the party.

Your problem is a direct consequence of the new Gateway Intents, put in place by Discord on their API.

Not to worry, this is an easy fix. Just go to https://discord.com/developers/applications, select your App, then got to the bot section. [You're then looking for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNFG6.png). Just enable **Server Members Intent**.

If everything went to plan, this should transparently fix your issue without even needing to recompile. Short of that, feel free to ask again.